# How to find ranges in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In column A, I have some numbers, formatted as text due to leading zeros:

```
+-------------+
|  A          |
+-------------+
| 01011111001 |
| 01011111002 |
| 01011111003 |
| 01011111012 |
| 01011111013 |
+------+------+
```

Using column A as input, I want to populate two other columns, B and C, like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|  B          |  C           |
+-------------+--------------+
| 01011111001 | 010111111003 |
| 01011111012 | 010111111013 |
| 01011111115 |              |
| 01011111117 |              |
| 01011111019 | 0101111111020|
+------+------+--------------+
```

When there is a sequence of numbers (like a range), I want to have the starting number in col B and ending number in Col C.

However, if it is a single number, that can remain in col B itself.

I have 10000 numbers which has ranges and single numbers want to separate as above

How can this be accomplished in Excel?

Comment: What's the relation between the new and old data, I don't see any pattern, you increase only part of the numbers, sometimes by 1, sometimes by 2. Why did you tagged your question as [tag:vba], this should be easier to done with [tag:worksheet-function]. What about this: `=TEXT(B1+1,"00000000000")`

Comment: @Máté Juhász - I have explained the table in words based on my understanding

Answer (score 0):

Using an extended sample data

```
01011111002
01011111003
01011111004
01011111005
01011111006
01011111008
01011111009
01011111011
01011111012
01011111013
01011111014
01011111015
01011111016
01011111017
01011111018
01011111020
01011111023
01011111026
01011111027
01011111028
01011111031
01011111032
01011111033
01011111034
```

and assuming that it is a sorted list, here are the steps that can help:

1) Define a name `pool`, which includes the data range + one more cell, which is empty.

[image]

2) Define a name `nn`, which counts the size of the `pool` as

```
=ROWS(pool)
```

3) Define a name `newrange` to be a formula:

```
=MOD((-1+(N(OFFSET(pool,1,,nn-1)-OFFSET(pool,,,nn-1)<>1)*ROW(OFFSET(pool,,,nn-1)))),nn)+1
```

4) Select the range next to the `pool` in column `B` and enter an array formula 
(press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=newrange
```

enter `0` below the last cell and select:

[image]

5) Next, copy this selection, paste as values and sort ascending:

[image]

6) Enter in `C1`:

```
=IF(OFFSET($A$1,B1,)>0,OFFSET($A$1,B1,),"")
```

7) Enter in `D1`:

```
=IF(OFFSET($A$1,B2-1,)=C1,"",OFFSET($A$1,B2-1,))
```

8) Select `C1:D1` and drag/copy down until empty cells appear in column `C`:

[image]